# получение JSON в ajax, php

Tags: php, ajax, json

есть небольшой скрипт поиска сделан на php (работает и получает ответ без подключения ajax)

**php скрипт**

```
   class Search_class extends Db{
                public    function search(){
    $params =  $_POST['search'];    
    $query = $this->db->prepare("SELECT * FROM regions WHERE title LIKE ?");
    $query->bindValue(1, "%$params%", PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $query->execute();  
            $result_search = array();
        while($row = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
            $result_search[] = $row;
        }   
        $result_search = array('answer' => 'yes');
            return json_encode($result_search);
        }
    }

$search = new Search_class();
if( isset($_POST['search']) && $_POST['search'] ){
$res_search =   $search->search();
echo $res_search;
}
```

**запрос ajax**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#form').click(function(event) {
        var json; 
    var values = $("#search").val();
    event.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url:"includes.php",
            dataType : "json",
            data: {values:values},
            cache: false,
            success: function(res){ 
            json = jQuery.parseJSON(res);
                alert(json.answer);

          },
        });
    });
});
```

**форма html**

```
   <form  action="" method="post">
       <input id="search" name="search"/>
    <input id="form"  type="submit" class="search-go" name="go-search" value="поиск"  />
     </form>
```

если с ajax. то firebug во вкладке response ничего не выводит, alert тоже не выводится(совсем не выводится)

Comment: скорее всего надо не `return json_encode($result_search);`, а `echo  json_encode($result_search); die();`  Именно чтобы вывести данные в поток, а не просто вернуть

Comment: вы в `_POST` не передаете `search`. `data: { search: $("#input").val() }`

Comment: @Сергей Мишин, дополнил php скрипт, echo json_encode($result_search); die(); - это изменение не повлияло

Comment: @teran, не #input, а #search, и такой вариант точно так же работает

Comment: `dataType : "json",` означает что от сервера придет `json` поэтому не надо `jQuery.parseJSON(res)`.

Comment: @u_mulder, такой же результат, firebug только post отправляет, а ответ пуст

Comment: @teran, все в консоле просмотрел ничего ничего не ругается, другой момент, я убрал весь php код и оставил includes.php пустым, так результат тот же, хотя сам php скрипт без ajax работает

Comment: А метод `onclick` у вас на что повешан?

Answer (score 1):

В Вашем JSON запросе в свойстве `data` передаётся строка поиска с ключом `values`, а на стороне PHP вы проверяете `$_POST['search']`, которого в теле запроса нет.

Вам следует или переименовать `values` в `search` вот так:

```js
$.ajax({
  type: 'POST',
  url: "includes.php",
  dataType: "json",
  data: {search: values}, // вот тут вместо values - search
  cache: false,
  success: function(res) { 
    json = jQuery.parseJSON(res);
    alert(json.answer);
  },
```

Или, наоборот, в PHP скрипте вместо `$_POST['search']` проверять наличие `$_POST['values']` (и, соответственно, везде, где `'search'`, писать `'values'`):

```php
if( isset($_POST['values']) && $_POST['values'] ){
    $res_search = $search->search();
    echo $res_search;
}
```

Comment: в обоих случая в консоле ко вкладке параметры **search:текст поста** , во вкладке ответ НИЧЕГО, даже alert не срабатывает(вообще не выводится)